# Yum upgrade to PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, linux, lamp, yum

PHP 5.4 was just released. Is there any way to upgrade my yum installation of PHP to 5.4 right away, or do I have to wait for package repos to start offering it?

Comment: This is a question for serverfault.

Comment: Ah thanks, hadn't ever been to that site before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to wait, or you can download the source and manually compile it. I would recommend not installing 5.4 on production servers for at least 2-4 weeks.

Comment: Cool, thanks. And agreed about production servers, this would be for my own personal hobby sites.

Comment: CentOS upsteam PHP is still on 5.3.3, haha... so will probably be a year before they get to 5.4. The EPEL may have 5.4 available sooner, http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL